# Complex nesting of partials and templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question involves how to go about dealing with complex nesting of **templates** (also called **partials**) in an AngularJS application.

The best way to describe my situation is with an image I created:

[image: AngularJS Page Diagram]

As you can see this has the potential to be a fairly complex application with lots of nested models.

The application is single-page, so it loads an **index.html** that contains a div element in the DOM with the `ng-view` attribute.

**For circle 1**, You see that there is a Primary navigation that loads the appropriate templates into the `ng-view`.  I'm doing this by passing `$routeParams` to the main app module.  Here is an example of what's in my app:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.                     
            when("/job/:jobId/zones/:zoneId", { controller: JobDetailController, templateUrl: 'assets/job_list_app/templates/zone_edit.html' }).
            when("/job/:jobId/initial_inspection", { controller: JobDetailController, templateUrl: 'assets/job_list_app/templates/initial_inspection.html' }).
            when("/job/:jobId/zones/:zoneId/rooms/:roomId", { controller: JobDetailController, templateUrl: 'assets/job_list_app/templates/room_edit.html' })       

    }]);
```

**In circle 2**, the template that is loaded into the `ng-view` has an additional **sub-navigation**.  This sub-nav then needs to load templates into the area below it - but since ng-view is already being used, I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

I know that I can include additional templates within the 1st template, but these templates are all going to be pretty complex.  I would like to keep all the templates separate in order to make the application easier to update and not have a dependency on the parent template having to be loaded in order to access its children.

**In circle 3**, you can see things get even more complex.  There is the potential that the sub-navigation templates will have a **2nd sub-navigation** that will need to load its own templates as well into the area in **circle 4**

**How does one go about structuring an AngularJS app to deal with such complex nesting of templates while keeping them all separate from one another?**

Comment: If you're still following this thread, I added a link to a new AngularUI project to address this and a third demo that is powered by subroutes without needing a directive to my answer.

Comment: what about this one? http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2441-Nested-Views-Routing-And-Deep-Linking-With-AngularJS.htm

Comment: prettiest question I've seen in a long time :)

Comment: Would be great to add links to the alternatives directly in the question here. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
https://github.com/artch/angular-route-segment
https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-routing

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Well, since you can currently only have one ngView directive... I use nested directive controls. This allows you to set up templating and inherit (or isolate) scopes among them. Outside of that I use ng-switch or even just ng-show to choose which controls I'm displaying based on what's coming in from $routeParams.

**EDIT** Here's some example pseudo-code to give you an idea of what I'm talking about. With a nested sub navigation.

Here's the main app page

```
<!-- primary nav -->
<a href="#/page/1">Page 1</a>
<a href="#/page/2">Page 2</a>
<a href="#/page/3">Page 3</a>

<!-- display the view -->
<div ng-view>
</div>
```

Directive for the sub navigation

```
app.directive('mySubNav', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
           current: '=current'
        },
        templateUrl: 'mySubNav.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
        }
    };
});
```

template for the sub navigation

```
<a href="#/page/1/sub/1">Sub Item 1</a>
<a href="#/page/1/sub/2">Sub Item 2</a>
<a href="#/page/1/sub/3">Sub Item 3</a>
```

template for a main page (from primary nav)

```
<my-sub-nav current="sub"></my-sub-nav>

<ng-switch on="sub">
  <div ng-switch-when="1">
      <my-sub-area1></my-sub-area>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="2">
      <my-sub-area2></my-sub-area>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="3">
      <my-sub-area3></my-sub-area>
  </div>
</ng-switch>
```

Controller for a main page. (from the primary nav)

```
app.controller('page1Ctrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
     $scope.sub = $routeParams.sub;
});
```

Directive for a Sub Area

```
app.directive('mySubArea1', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'mySubArea1.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
            //controller for your sub area.
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I like ProLoser's solution better, we do something like that on our app and it has worked fine. The problem with blesh's solution is the controller code going into the directives. Usually the controller that that you specify in a directive is one which works closely with the directive for ex: ngModelCtrl which works closely with the input and other directives. In your case putting the controller code within a directive would be a code smell, it is actually an independent controller.

Comment: @blesh, nice ! It seems really good explained but as a good JS programmer and beginner in AngularJS I coulnt catch that well... Me and the community would really enjoy a JSFiddle link to a working sample using that approach. Diggin it around would be easy to understand ! :) Thanks

Comment: I think this solution should be a first answer for any questions kind of 'nested view didn't work'. Just because it's much more close to the Angular ideology instead of using ui-router and etc. Thanks.

Comment: So the answer is directives?

Comment: to highlight the sub-nav items you could use this:
http://coder1.com/articles/angularjs-managing-active-nav-elements
is this a good way to do it?

Answer (score 199):

#### *UPDATE:* [Check out AngularUI's new project to address this problem](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

---

For subsections it's as easy as leveraging strings in ng-include:

```
<ul id="subNav">
  <li><a ng-click="subPage='section1/subpage1.htm'">Sub Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="subPage='section1/subpage2.htm'">Sub Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="subPage='section1/subpage3.htm'">Sub Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
<ng-include src="subPage"></ng-include>
```

Or you can create an object in case you have links to sub pages all over the place:

```
$scope.pages = { page1: 'section1/subpage1.htm', ... };
```

```
<ul id="subNav">
  <li><a ng-click="subPage='page1'">Sub Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="subPage='page2'">Sub Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a ng-click="subPage='page3'">Sub Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
<ng-include src="pages[subPage]"></ng-include>
```

Or you can even use `$routeParams`

```
$routeProvider.when('/home', ...);
$routeProvider.when('/home/:tab', ...);
$scope.params = $routeParams;
```

```
<ul id="subNav">
  <li><a href="#/home/tab1">Sub Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/home/tab2">Sub Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/home/tab3">Sub Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
<ng-include src=" '/home/' + tab + '.html' "></ng-include>
```

You can also put an ng-controller at the top-most level of each partial

Comment: I like your solution better. i am a newb to Angular and this seems much more understandable from how i see the web until today. who knows, may be blesh uses more of the angular framework to do it, but it seems like you nailed it with fewer lines of code in a more sensible way. thanks!

Comment: @ProLooser maybe you meant this link https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router  ...the one you pasted is broken

Comment: I'm having the same design issue as the OP. Has anyone tried AngularUI  state mechanism ? I'm quite reluctant to using yet another 3rd party library and I'd rather stick with AngularJS 'way of doing things'. But on the other hand, the routing system seems to be its Achilles' heel... @PhillipKregg, what did you end up using to solve this scenario ?

Comment: So with this method, do you end up sharing the scope between the parent template and the sub-template?

Comment: You can specify `<div ng-include="'/home/' + tab + '.html'" ng-controller="SubCtrl"></div>` in order to use a separate controller/scope for the sub-template.  Or just specify the `ngController` directive anywhere within your sub-template(s) to use a different controller for each partial.

Comment: Would you choose the nested routing project or the `strings + ng-include`?  Just curious, i'm probably just going to use the ng-include thing until the project is stable.

Comment: @DerekAdair the project is fairly stable (despite version number) and in use in production in a few places. It prevents unnecessary controller reloading, and is a much better alternative to my suggested solution.

Comment: I tried the variable approach in src='' and it seems to try to load the page w/o interpolating the variable first, then will load the full page.  Caused routing loops for me.  I had to generate the URL in the controller completely.

Answer (score 27):

You may checkout this library for the same purpose also:

http://angular-route-segment.com

It looks like what you are looking for, and it is much simpler to use than ui-router. From the [demo site](http://angular-route-segment.com/src/example/):

JS:

```
$routeSegmentProvider.

when('/section1',          's1.home').
when('/section1/:id',      's1.itemInfo.overview').
when('/section2',          's2').

segment('s1', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/section1.html',
    controller: MainCtrl}).
within().
    segment('home', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/section1/home.html'}).
    segment('itemInfo', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/section1/item.html',
        controller: Section1ItemCtrl,
        dependencies: ['id']}).
    within().
        segment('overview', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/section1/item/overview.html'}).
```

Top-level HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{active: $routeSegment.startsWith('s1')}">
        <a href="/section1">Section 1</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active: $routeSegment.startsWith('s2')}">
        <a href="/section2">Section 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="contents" app-view-segment="0"></div>
```

Nested HTML:

```
<h4>Section 1</h4>
Section 1 contents.
<div app-view-segment="1"></div>
```

Comment: Artem, your's is the best solution I've found to date!  I like the fact that you extend angular route rather than replace it as angular ui does.

Answer (score 17):

I too was struggling with nested views in Angular.

Once I got a hold of [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) I knew I was never going back to angular default routing functionality.

Here is an example application that uses multiple levels of views nesting

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$httpProvider) {
// navigate to view1 view by default
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/view1");

$stateProvider
    .state('view1', {
        url: '/view1',
        templateUrl: 'partials/view1.html',
        controller: 'view1.MainController'
    })
    .state('view1.nestedViews', {
        url: '/view1',
        views: {
            'childView1': { templateUrl: 'partials/view1.childView1.html' , controller: 'childView1Ctrl'},
            'childView2': { templateUrl: 'partials/view1.childView2.html', controller: 'childView2Ctrl' },
            'childView3': { templateUrl: 'partials/view1.childView3.html', controller: 'childView3Ctrl' }
        }
    })

    .state('view2', {
        url: '/view2',
    })

    .state('view3', {
        url: '/view3',
    })

    .state('view4', {
        url: '/view4',
    });
});
```

As it can be seen there are 4 main views (view1,view2,view3,view4) and view1 has 3 child views.

Comment: What is the purpose of injecting `$httpProvider`? I don't see it used anywhere.

Comment: @Aaron app.config doesn't end in this piece of code and may be  **$httpProvider** is used somewhere else

Answer (score 4):

You may use ng-include to avoid using nested ng-views.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude
http://plnkr.co/edit/ngdoc:example-example39@snapshot?p=preview

My index page I use ng-view. Then on my sub pages which I need to have nested frames. I use    ng-include. 
The demo shows a dropdown. I replaced mine with a link  ng-click. 
In the function I would put    $scope.template = $scope.templates[0]; or $scope.template = $scope.templates[1];

```
$scope.clickToSomePage= function(){
  $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular ui-router supports nested views. I haven't used it yet but looks very promising.

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/