# How do I setup nested views in AngularJS?

Tags: uiview, angularjs, nested

I have an application with various *screens*. Each screen is assigned a URL, such as `#`, `mails`, `contacts`, and so on.

In my main HTML file I have an `ng-view` element which updates according to the route the user selects. So far, so good.

Now some of these screens have a sub-navigation. E.g., `#mails` does have an inbox and a sent folder. They present themselfes with two columns: The sub-navigation on the left, the mails of the appropriate folder on the right.

When you navigate to `#mails`, it shall redirect you to `#mails/inbox`, so that basically *inbox* is the default sub-view for mails.

How could I set this up?

The only approach I can currently think of (I am quite new to AngularJS, hence forgive me if this question is a little bit naive) is to have two views, one for `#mails/inbox`, and the other for `#mails/sent`.

When you select a route, these views are loaded. When you select `#mails` it simply redirects you to `#mails/inbox`.

But this means that both views must use an `ng-include` for the sub-navigation. Somehow this feels wrong to me.

What I'd like more is to have nested views: The top one switches between screens such as mails, contacts, and so on, and the bottom one changes between sub-views such as inbox, sent, and so on.

How would I solve this?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no alternative to using ng-include as of now. That may change in the future.

Comment: Take a look at [AngularJS - Complex nesting of partials and templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863663/angularjs-complex-nesting-of-partials-and-templates) and check out [Angular ui-route](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

Comment: Yep, @Stewie is right. `ng-swith` is right approach for now

Comment: ui-router is definitely able to to what you want. Check it out - I've used it with great success.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[AngularJS ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) solved my issues :-)

Comment: Hands down agree.  Before I could only handle basically single routes, but ui-router allows you to 'tunnel' to the place you want to be with minimal work/requests.

Answer (score 4):

Another library to check out: http://angular-route-segment.com

You can use it instead of built-in `ng-view` and `$route`.

Sample route config looks like this one:

```
$routeSegmentProvider.

when('/section1',          's1.home').
when('/section1/prefs',    's1.prefs').
when('/section1/:id',      's1.itemInfo.overview').
when('/section1/:id/edit', 's1.itemInfo.edit').
when('/section2',          's2').

segment('s1', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/section1.html',
    controller: MainCtrl}).

within().

    segment('home', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/section1/home.html'}).

    segment('itemInfo', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/section1/item.html',
        controller: Section1ItemCtrl,
        dependencies: ['id']}).

    within().

        segment('overview', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/section1/item/overview.html'}).

        segment('edit', {
             templateUrl: 'templates/section1/item/edit.html'}).

        up().

    segment('prefs', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/section1/prefs.html'}).

    up().

segment('s2', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/section2.html',
    controller: MainCtrl});
```