# How do I dynamically load multiple templates using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, coming from a PHP background where I do all the template aggregation on the server. With PHP I would grab several templates, mash them together, then send it to the clients browser. AngularJS allows me to insert a template using `ng-view`. This is great, but it doesn't handle the case where the template that I insert may include tags that are placeholders for other templates. For example, I may have the following as one of my templates:

```
<div class="some_class">
    <div class="another_class">
        {content}
    </div>
</div>
```

In PHP I would insert this template, then replace the contents of `{content}` with another template. In AngularJS I know how to insert the main template (using `ng-view`), but I'm not sure how to dynamically load my "partial template" into the `{content}` tag. How is this suppose to be done with AngularJS?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router perhaps?

Comment: Use `ui-router` like akonsu said.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A straightforward approach would be to use the [ngInclude directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude):

```html
<div class="some_class">
  <div class="another_class">
    <ng-include src="templatePath"></ng-include>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, in Controller that is associated with this template you can define the `templatePath`  variable dynamically:

```js
function MyCtrl($scope){
  $scope.templatePath = // define this var dynamically here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `ng-view` to nest multiple templates is not currently supported natively in Angular.js. There are, however, multiple options to emulate that functionality. See the answers in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637350/nesting-ng-views-in-angular-js) for several of those options, including the ui-router suggested by akonsu.