# How to set a Nested view inside a multiple views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, nested-views

I've two named views and an unnamed view as the follow:

```
//department.html
<div class="col-md-2">
        <div ui-view="sideBar"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-10">

        <div ui-view="content"></div>

        <div ui-view></div>

 </div>
```

And my routes:

```
.state('Support', {
    url: '/support',
    views: {
       '': { templateUrl: 'app/components/department/department.html'  },

       'sideBar@Support': {
                           templateUrl: 'app/shared/sideBar/sideBar.html',
                           controller: 'SideBarController'
                          },

        'content@Support':{
                           templateUrl: 'app/components/department/support/partial-support.html',
                           controller: 'SupportController'
                          },

      }        
  })


.state('Support.view', {
  url: '/view',
  template: '<b> Hi there nested!!</b>'
});
```

What do i need :

- `localhost/support` : this is a parent url, in that url two named views are injected(sideBar and content) which works for me.
- `localhost/support/view` : in this router i want a child view that will replace the `content` view OR replace both multiple views.

The problem is:
 I can't get the nested view working, i'm doing something wrong?

PS: I've read the ui-router doc and see other questions i can't find any similar scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637350/nesting-ng-views-in-angular-js

Comment: No, this thread is about ng-views, i'm using already ui-router...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario is working when NOT having html5Mode enabled. There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qPPNbqu0IREPaMiP0AGo?p=preview).

I just used these links:

```
<a ui-sref="Support">
<a ui-sref="Support.view">
```

And the state as is - works.

In case, that you have html5Mode enabled, you must also configure your server. But as [this updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/H8uRnTGi2jnChpdnptVm?p=preview) shows, it is working again, even with html5Mode enabled

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true});
```

Check a version

- [without html5Mode](http://plnkr.co/edit/qPPNbqu0IREPaMiP0AGo?p=preview)
- [with html5Mode enabled](http://plnkr.co/edit/H8uRnTGi2jnChpdnptVm?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about html5Mode, but the problem still not resolved i want  to completely replace the content of **content@Support**, in other words when i click the **Support.view** link i don't want to see **content@Support** 's content...

Comment: I created an adjusted plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/0nls7qhL40B792uRZ6sp?p=preview, which does change the content of the **content@Support** on a Support.view... to an empty stuff. I used native UI-Router solution - multi `views :{}` Hope that this helps