# How use body onload in a ui-view

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am newbie with Angular! I have this code:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function init() {
    }
</script>

<body onload="init();">
    <div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:100%;height:100%;'>
        <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
            <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:332px;"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:268px;"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="year_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_header">
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_data">
        </div>      
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I use this in another view using ui-view?

Comment: Did you tried to create a service and call it from controller ?

Comment: 3 Links for your: http://jan.varwig.org/archive/angularjs-views-vs-directives this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637350/nesting-ng-views-in-angular-js and this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views :)