# How to create a layout template for angular routing?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute

I use angular routing:

```
angular.module("app-test", ["ngRoute"]).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $routeProvider.when("/",
        {
            controller: "firstController",
            templateUrl: "/views/first/index.html"
        });

    $routeProvider.when("/second",
        {
            controller: "secondController",
            templateUrl: "/views/second/index.html"
        });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
});
```

But all my views of the different routes (e.g. **views/first/index.html, views/second/index.html**, etc.) have repeating html code like loading panels, messages, etc.
How can I **outsource** those common syntax in for example a **layout html page** that is used together **with all the templateUrl** views of the angular routing?

For example if every templateUrl has following html code - `<div>{{message}}</div>` - I would like to put this code in an extra html file which will be included in the templateUrl while the angular routing is getting the view.

Comment: did you use`ng-view`?

Comment: Of course. Otherwise the routing wouldn't work. It works perfectly fine. I just want to avoid repeated code in the views...

Comment: if you want to have a nested view. I recommend you to use `ui-router` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637350/nesting-ng-views-in-angular-js

Comment: Just make reusable components? In your example, a `<custom-message prop="message">`, `<page-header>`, `<page-footer>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-include`. But you can also use the same View (html) with different controllers:

```
        $routeProvider.when("/",
        {
            controller: "firstController",
            templateUrl: "/views/shared.html"
        });

    $routeProvider.when("/second",
        {
            controller: "secondController",
            templateUrl: "/views/shared.html"
        });
```

Please also note that a "views" folder doesn't scale very well. It works better to have a feature directory for each feature that contains all the pieces needed to build that feature. Shared stuff can get a bit dicey--if you know in advance you're going to share it, you can put it in a "shared" or "common" directory, but sometimes you wind up using it from the feature where it was first used.