# AngularJS advanced tabs - two ng-transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Angular UI, has support only for basic tabs.
I wanted to create a directive that would support nested tabs & advanced headings (that can include html).

I think, that the best syntax would be

```
<tabs>
    <tab>
        <title><i class="myIcon"></i> Title 1</title>
        <p>Content 1</p>
    </tab>
    <tab>
        <title class="pull-right">Title 2 (Nested)</title>
            <tab>
                <title>Title 2.1</title>
                <p>Content 2.1</p>
            </tab>
        <p>Content 2</p>
    </tab>
</tabs>
```

My problem with this approach, is that I would need 2 ng-transclude - one for panes and one for titles.

As it would be very easy to do the first ng-transclude (just like in the tutorial):

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="pane in panes" transclude-title></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" ng-transclude="">
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't have any idea how can I transclude titles here? 
How can I preserve nested structure of tabs ?

Maybe there is a better solution to this problem ?

Comment: You can get the transclusion as the 3rd parameter to your `compile` function, and manually traverse it.

Comment: Why don't you create your own directives. Based on your statement of "nested tabs", you could check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863663/angularjs-complex-nesting-of-partials-and-templates) article which demonstrates how nested directives can be used to create nested views (or nested tabs in your case).

Answer (score 6):

This is a multiple transclude example. I hope it points you into the right direction.

http://plnkr.co/edit/wpgvgr5h6nAQDOZYEHNI?p=preview

Comment: I'm interested in this code, but the plnkr is broken. Could you fix the plnkr so I can learn more about compile and nested transclusion?

Comment: @Martijn I think I corrected now. Can you try it and let me know if it is ok? Link here: http://plnkr.co/edit/wpgvgr5h6nAQDOZYEHNI

Comment: Yes it does work now, thanks! What was wrong? I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @Martijn I made several changes:
1 - updated to recent angular version
2 - used angular-ui-bootstrap tabset directive instead of the one I had
3 - stored the actual html string for title and content instead of the jquery selector result -- the html was being lost on the way -- I think this was the key change