# ui-router: intermediate templates

Tags: angularjs, templates, angular-ui-router, angular-material, nested-views

> **Final Edit**: [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NO8ZEDvQrPDCCKRy6voW?p=preview) with the transcluded directive.
>
> **Edit**: I made  [a first plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TDCG09iPmBCkl95ue89u?p=preview) with the solution given in the first answer. It works, but it's not the desired behaviour, because the template contains all the partial.
>
> I made a [second plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kXZbAV7MNJjhHbVBnA7U?p=info) with what I hope to achieve (but it doesn't work, obviously). I think it's mostly because the template is not the *parent* of the partial, but it is contained in it, so ui-router doesn't understand very well what I want.
>
> Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

We are building a website with Angular Material and ui-router, and all our content page share the same "container", because we always want the same responsive behaviour.

The code of this generic container would be something like:

```
  <div class="layout-content">
    <div layout="column" layout-align="center">
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
        <section class="layout-fixed-width md-whiteframe-z1" flex-sm="100" flex-gt-sm="90">

        {{content placed here}}

        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The header can differ in all pages, so the structure we have would basically be:

[image]

The question is, how can this be achieved in ui-router? We have done some nested views, but I don't see how to do a generic template so the code could be something like:

```
<form>
  <md-toolbar/>
  <div ui-view="generic-template">
      <div ui-view="my-content"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Ideally we would want to define only one time the generic-template view, and use it in all our modules.

In the [nested states and nested views documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views) I see mostly nested state stuff, but what we want is really only a plain html template, so maybe we are over-complicating this, and an easier way is possible (I'm quite sure it's the case). I've also checked [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863663/complex-nesting-of-partials-and-templates), where one of the answers say that ui-router should be the solution, but not much more.

Maybe we should do a directive instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe we should do a directive instead?

A directive with a transcluded `ui-view` certainly seems to give you what you're looking for. This saves you from cluttering up your routing logic with something that has nothing to do with routing.

`genericTemplate.html`:

```
<div>
    <p>Generic content</p>
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</div>
```

Somewhere in your js:

```
angular.module('formApp')
    .directive('genericTemplate', function () {
        return {
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: 'genericTemplate.html'
        };
    });
```

In your html:

```
<body ng-app='formApp'>
    <div generic-template>
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

> **Edit**: working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NO8ZEDvQrPDCCKRy6voW?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be it! I've added a working plunker demonstrating that it works. We'll try to implement it in our project ASAP and let you know.

Comment: This is definitely the best choice. I was also trying to implement it with a transcluded directive, but without success. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

It can be achieved combining named views and abstract states.
The 'key' here is to define an abstract state with a view for the layout (or generic template, if we follow the nomenclature of your original post).

**Abstract state:**

```
  .state('master', {
      abstract:  true,
      views: {
        generic_template: {
          templateUrl: 'genericTemplate.html'
        }
      }
    })
```

Then, you have to set this abstract state as parent to the child views. So, the child view will inherit the generic template view. Example:

```
.state('one', {
    url: '/one',
    templateUrl: 'one.html',
    parent: 'master'
})
```

In your index.html, you have to use a named view for the generic template, and inside it, another unnamed view. Something like this:

```
<body>

  <div ui-view="generic_template">
    <div ui-view></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IzoNqiGdTXoOm6C20tXx?p=preview) with a complete working example. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: I edited my question, unfortunately it doesn't cover 100% what I was asking for. Thank you though!